# Given a 100mbit connection, what is your max downstream speed?

Tags: networking, tcpip

I'm a (very) junior sysadmin and was asked this question on an interview. The answer was 96mbit/s.

I know this is related to network overhead but I cannot find any good information on why this should be 96mbit/s. For IPv4, network overhead accounts for 2% which means this should be 98mbit/s.

Can anyone explain this? Or provide any good info on network overhead? The topic is very hazy for me - why is 2% of the connection taken up by network overhead?

Comment: Over the years I've heard different figures bandied around for "overhead", anywhere from 1-5%. Realistically it's in the eye of the beholder for example are you looking at network throughput to/from a client or the actual data received. For example if you think about download a file through FTP. You can measure the speed of data to/from the client's network interface or the actual data received via FTP. I think 2% is fair for general network overhead and perhaps another 2% is fair for protocol overhead giving roughly 4%

Comment: This question is vague and ambiguous. Should we assume TCP? If so, should the "downstream speed" include only data or TCP address and headers too? If they really wanted a specific, numerical answer (rather than a discussion about what data rates you typically see and why) then it's a very bad question and reflects negatively on the interviewer. (If pressed for a number, I would have answered, "slightly over 90MB/s".)

Comment: A pointless question for an interview.

Answer (score 6):

Unless this question was used "to see how you think," it's not a great interview question. If they only had one right answer then they're doing it wrong.

The crux of this question is whether you understand protocol overhead or not. The first thing I would ask if given this question is, at what level in the stack is this max downstream speed going to be measured at?

If they said at the Ethernet protocol level then 98Mb/s would have been a very close answer since it's actually 97.53Mb/s (without 802.1q tags) [sidenote: capitalization is important when talking about speeds (e.g. lowercase m is milli, uppercase M is Mega)]

If at the TCP/IP protocol level then things get trickier. You have more choices, is it TCP or UDP, is it IPv4 or IPv6, are TCP timestamps being used or not, are 802.1q tags being used, etc.

For IPv4/TCP/Timestamps off/No options/No 802.1q it would be 94.93Mb/s.
For IPv4/UDP/No 802.1q it would be 95.7Mb/s.

If you want to learn more about protocol overhead I highly recommend this post by Phillip Dykstra on the topic:
http://sd.wareonearth.com/~phil/net/overhead/